# typeahead with show more option in angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, bootstrap-typeahead, ngx-bootstrap

I have created typeahead and i am getting data in it. But now i want to add custom value like "SHOW MORE" in my typeahead as last item in my list everytime. I am unable to do the same. Please suggest me solution to do the same.

html:-

```
<input [(ngModel)]="asyncSelected"
         [typeahead]="dataSource"
         (typeaheadLoading)="changeTypeaheadLoading($event)"
         (typeaheadNoResults)="changeTypeaheadNoResults($event)"
         (typeaheadOnSelect)="typeaheadOnSelect($event)"
         [typeaheadOptionsLimit]="7"
         typeaheadOptionField="name"
         placeholder="Search"
         typeaheadAsync="false"
         class="form-control">
```

i am getting data in but just want to add clickable footer or anything else that is suggested.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by using a custom ng-template for the results of my list. After the data of the typeahead widget is ready I added an empty element at the end of the result list. The template looks like this:

```
<ng-template #personSelectionTemplate let-model="item" let-index="index">
<div>{{model.firstName}}</div>
<button *ngIf="index >= persons.length-1;" class="btn btn-create" (click)="loadMoreSuggestions($event)">{{'loadMoreSuggestions'|translate}}</button></ng-template>
```